# Not getting more than 100 photos from facebook albums in php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am using `Facebbok Graph Api` to show to photos of `facebook` albums on my website. The issue is it is showing only 100 photos but my album is having more than 100 photos. I have tried something like this:

```
$album_image = $fb->get('/'.$album['id'].'/photos?fields=id,source,url&limit=500');   

$album_image = $fb->get('/'.$album['id'].'/photos?fields=id,source,url&limit=500');   

$album_images = $album_image->getDecodedBody();
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/Facebook/5.0.0, nearly at the bottom they have an example showing how to iterate over batches of pages using the `next` command. Maybe that will solve it.

Comment: @RST I have tried using **next** command ..but it limits photos to 100.

Comment: Sorry that is all I could find. Contact Facebook.

Comment: @RST  Sorry , the issue was in my code . This works ..thanks :)

Comment: @kristen: pls post u r code as answer so that other can get help from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'your app id',
  'app_secret' => 'your app secret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);

// Sets the default fallback access token so we don't have to pass it to each request
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken('app access token');

try {
  $response = $fb->get('/'your album id'/albums?fields=id,name,picture');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$album = $response->getDecodedBody();
$album_ids = array();
$album_info = array();
$album_images_id = array();

foreach ($album['data'] as $key => $value) {
  $album_ids[] = $value['id'];
  $album_info[$value['id']] = $value;

  $album_image = $fb->get('/'.$value['id'].'/photos?tab=album&fields=id,source,picture');
  $album_images = $album_image->getDecodedBody();
  $feedEdge = $album_image->getGraphEdge();

    // Page 2 (next 5 results)
    $nextFeed = $fb->next($feedEdge);

    foreach ($nextFeed as $status) {
      var_dump($status->asArray());
    }
}

?>
```